# Encoding and decoding by rearranging a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, encoding

I am trying to write two separate programs that could be used to encode and then decode a word or phrase.  Encoding requires checking that the length of the message (including spaces) is a 2-composite number.  That is, it has exactly two factors excluding 1 and itself.  If it is not 2-composite, 'X' must be added until it is 2-composite.  Then the actual encoding is done by arranging the message in a grid with the dimensions of its factors and reading down instead of across.  So the phrase "i am struggling here", has 20 characters and needs to become "i am struggling hereX" in order to be encoded, because 20 has too many factors. Then think of the message as

```
i am st
rugglin
g hereX
```

After being encoded, it reads, "irg u aghmge lrsietnX".

I understand how to make the list the right length by adding 'X', but I can't understand how to take every 7th character from the list to create a new list. This is what I have:

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

anagramEncode :: [Char] -> [Char]
anagramEncode (x:xs) = if (length (factors (length xs))) == 4 then [k | k <- 
???]
else anagramEncode (xs ++ ['X'])
```

Comment: How would you take the first character of every list?

Comment: When I use (x:xs), isn't x the first character of the list?

Comment: yes, but now you want to do this for every sublist.

Comment: So, do I need to create sublists based on how many factors there are?

Comment: well this problem has two subproblems: padding the input with `X`s, and transposing the list. The comment was more to help you constructing the transpose function.

Comment: It's a good use case for `Data.Matrix` once you get `[3,7]`

Comment: Padding is done with `xs ++ replicate n 'X'`. Package `split` has a function [`chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) in module `Data.List.Split` to turn `"i am struggling hereX"` into `["i am st", "rugglin", "g hereX"]`.  

Then there's  [`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) to turn it into `["irg", " u ", "agh", "mge", " lr", "sie", "tnX"]` and [`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=concat) to glue the pieces back together.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down into steps.

1. Identify the smallest 2-composite number that is `>=` the length of the input string.
2. Pad the ending of the string with `'X'` characters so that the length is 2-composite.
3. Split the padded string into a list of chunks where each chunk is the same length.
4. Transpose the chunks.
5. Concatenate the chunks back together.

We can start by using `length` to get the length of the input string. Next, we can use the [`primeFactors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Numbers-Primes.html#v:primeFactors) function from the `primes` package to find a number with only 2 prime factors.

The 2nd step can be accomplished using `++` and `replicate n 'X'` to append `n` characters to the end of the string.

The 3rd step can be accomplished using the [`chunksOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) function from the `split` package, using 1 of the factors from step 1 in order to split the string into chunks.

The last 2 steps are very easy, because that's the [`transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) and [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) functions.

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import Data.Numbers.Primes (primeFactors)
import Data.List (transpose)

anagramEncode :: String -> String
anagramEncode str = concat (transpose (chunksOf factor paddedString))
  where
    unpaddedLength = length str
    (paddedLength, factor) =
        head [(n, facHi) | n <- [unpaddedLength ..]
                         , [facLo, facHi] <- [primeFactors n] ]
    paddedString = str ++ replicate (paddedLength - unpaddedLength) 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is my solution. As mentioned in my comment the `Data.Matrix` package seems ideal for this job due to it's data structure and built in transposing (rows <-> columns) ability.

So this is the code;

```
import Data.Bool (bool)
import Data.Matrix

factors :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
factors n = [(x, n `div` x) | x <- [2..limit], n `mod` x == 0]
            where limit = truncate . sqrt . realToFrac $ n

twoComposites :: [(Int,Int)] -- infinite list of composites only with 2 composers
twoComposites = foldr (\n rs -> let ts  = factors n  -- tuples of composers
                                in bool rs (ts ++ rs) (length ts == 1)) [] [2..]      

getComposites :: Int -> (Int,Int)
getComposites n = head . filter ((>= n) . uncurry (*)) $ twoComposites

composeMtx :: String -> Matrix Char
composeMtx s = uncurry fromList ts swx
               where len = length s
                     ts  = getComposites len
                     lwx = uncurry (*) $ ts               -- length with X
                     swx = s ++ replicate (lwx - len) 'X' -- string with X

encode :: String -> String
encode = toList . transpose . composeMtx
```

Note: It's already 2AM here and I am out of beer and cigars... So all detailed explanation will follow tomorrow. Yet.. lets put this under some test... (also thanks for @4castle for pointing out my overlook)

```
*Main> encode "i am struggling here"   -- 20 chrs adds one X fills up to (3,7)
"irg u aghmge lrsietn "
(0.01 secs, 155,240 bytes)


*Main> encode "i am struggling here "  -- 21 chrs adds no Xs already (3,7)
"il ianmg  shterrueg gX"
(0.01 secs, 159,160 bytes)

*Main> encode "i am struggling here  " -- 22 chrs adds no Xs already (2,11)
"il ianmg  shterrueg g "
(0.01 secs, 158,984 bytes)

*Main> encode "i am struggling here   " -- 23 chrs adds 2 Xs fills up to (5,5)
"isg   tlh arie munrX ggeX"
(0.01 secs, 159,448 bytes)
```

Explanation:

- `factors` is an efficient function to calculate composing numbers. i.e. to check 100 it only counts up from 2 to 10 (sqrt 100). 2 yields (2,50), 4 yields (4,25), 5 yields (5,20), ... 10 yields (10,10). I allow (10,10) although 10 is duplicated, since this algorithm needs composer pairs to be used for Matrix dimensions.
- `twoComposites` gives us an infinite list of composite numbers which only have 2 composers. The `bool` function (`a -> a -> Bool -> a`) is a ternary test just like JavaScript's `? :` and takes 3 parameters like `bool negativeResponse positiveResponce condition` In Haskell left side is almost always negative.. so keep in mind that's different in JS.
- `getComposites` is a function when fed with an integer returns a tuple with two composers which yield either same or the closest bigger composite number which has only two composers. The `uncurry` (`(a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`) function takes an operator which accepts 2 parameters and applies it to the elements of a tuple with two elements. So `uncurry (*) (3,7)` will result 21.
- `composeMtx` when fed with a string pads it with necessary number of 'x's and places it row by row in a matrix.

So this is what it produces;

```
*Main> composeMtx "Once i had a black and white cat called Jessuro. He used to run on the roof all day long"

( 'O' 'n' 'c' 'e' ' ' 'i' ' ' 'h' 'a' 'd' ' ' 'a' ' ' )
( 'b' 'l' 'a' 'c' 'k' ' ' 'a' 'n' 'd' ' ' 'w' 'h' 'i' )
( 't' 'e' ' ' 'c' 'a' 't' ' ' 'c' 'a' 'l' 'l' 'e' 'd' )
( ' ' 'J' 'e' 's' 's' 'u' 'r' 'o' '.' ' ' 'H' 'e' ' ' )
( 'u' 's' 'e' 'd' ' ' 't' 'o' ' ' 'r' 'u' 'n' ' ' 'o' )
( 'n' ' ' 't' 'h' 'e' ' ' 'r' 'o' 'o' 'f' ' ' 'a' 'l' )
( 'l' ' ' 'd' 'a' 'y' ' ' 'l' 'o' 'n' 'g' 'X' 'X' 'X' )
```

- encode function is pretty straightforward... You may need to check [`Data.Matrix.transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html#v:transpose)

So;

```
*Main> encode "Once i had a black and white cat called Jessuro. He used to run on the roof all day long"
"Obt unlnleJs  ca eetdeccsdha kas eyi tut   a rorlhnco ooada.rond l ufg wlHn Xahee aX id olX"
(0.01 secs, 485,112 bytes)
```

Comment: `(> n)` could probably be `(>= n)`. That way your second test case doesn't need to expand from 21 chars to 22 chars (since 21 is already 2-composite).